# Mask NetCDF file data with multiple variables from shapefile in Python

Tags: python, netcdf, extract-by-mask

Most of the solutions to this I've seen online only work on 3-D time series data, but my NetCDF files has more than one variable.

It has a data variable named Albedo and I need to plot it using a shapefile.

What I currently do is:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader

filename="202205.nc4"

map_dataset=Dataset(filename,maskandscale=True,mmap=False)
   
lats=map_dataset.variables['lat'][:]
lons=map_dataset.variables['lon'][:]
elements  = map_dataset.variables['ALBEDO'][0, :, :]    #only 1 entry for time
   
ax   = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
   
plt.contourf(lons, lats, elements, cmap = 'magma', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.title('India')
   
ax.coastlines()
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS,edgecolor='white')
ax.set_extent([60, 120, 0, 40])   # regional map (x0, x1, y0, y1)  
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
   
plt.savefig('fig202205',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=400)
plt.show()
```

I have a shapefile `IND_adm0.shp` in the same directory, and I want to use this to plot only the Albedo data for India. All of the solutions I looked into use only data with variables, `lat,lon,time,data`, how do I do it for `lat,lon,time,data0,data1,data2`